# HTTP/2 for ALB with EKS on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-alb, amazon-eks

I'm experimenting with AWS EKS and have created the following setup:

- EKS cluster with a single service/pod/node
- AWS ALB ingress controller
- ALB

I try to configure the ALB to:

- create access logs
- provide HTTP/2 support

My alb ingress controller definition:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alb-ingress-controller
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: alb-ingress-controller
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - --ingress-class=alb
            - --cluster-name=eks
          image: docker.io/amazon/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.1.2
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: server
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      serviceAccountName: alb-ingress
      serviceAccount: alb-ingress
```

My service & ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-app
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "my-app"
  labels:
    app: my-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: "access_logs.s3.enabled=true,access_logs.s3.bucket=my-bucket,access_logs.s3.prefix=some-path"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: "routing.http2.enabled=true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: "my-app"
              servicePort: 5001
```

Result:

- ALB gets correctly created & traffic gets routed correctly
- but no HTTP/2 support (although AWS console says 'enabled' for HTTP/2, which is the default)
- and no ALB logs in S3 (although all permissions provided)

I have checked the ALB logs (kubectl logs -n kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | egrep -o alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)) and did not find any error message or warning.

Did anyone else get this to work?

Comment: Also, can someone make an "amazon-eks" tag? Does not seem to exist yet.

Comment: Got the S3 logs working by combining the two alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes statements into one. HTTP/2 on the other hand is not yet working.

Comment: And the HTTP/2 started working after enabling HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved these two issues in the meantime. Quick summary in case somebody else struggles with the same:

- all alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes need to be combined in a single comma-separated statement -> solved the S3 log issue

  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: "access_logs.s3.enabled=true,access_logs.s3.bucket=bucket-name,access_logs.s3.prefix=some-prefix"
- HTTPS needs to be enabled for HTTP/2 -> solved the HTTP/2 issue

  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS":443}]'
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: "arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-1:1234567891011:certificate/some-UID"

Comment: Could you share it?

Comment: Have updated the answer to add the actual configuration... hope that helps.